# How to use Static or Dynamic cast for the below program

Tags: c++

Could you please help me how to call the derived class non virtual function using Static or Dynamci cast.

I want to call derive call function "test" by using static or dynamic cast only.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class base
{
    public:
        virtual void call()
        {
            cout<<"I am base"<<endl;
        }
        /*void test()
        {
            cout<<"I am test"<<endl;
        }*/
};
class derive:public base
{
    public:
        void call()
        {
            cout<<"I am derive"<<endl;
        }
        void test()
        {
            cout<<"I am derived test"<<endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    derive d;
    base *bptr = &d;
    bptr->call();
    derive* dptr = dynamic_cast<derive *>(base);
    dptr->test();       
    return 0;
}
```

While compiling, I am getting below error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:34:47: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
     derive* dptr = dynamic_cast<derive *>(base);
                                               ^
```

Could you please tell me where I have mistaken.

Comment: Did you mean to case bptr, and not base (which is the type)?

Answer (score 4):

Remember `dynamic_cast< Type* >(ptr)`

Change

```
derive* dptr = dynamic_cast<derive*>(base);
```

to

```
derive* dptr = dynamic_cast<derive*>(bptr);
```

Which gives as result :

```
I am derive                                                                                                          
I am derived test
```

Because `base` is a type (if you use a uppercase on the first letter for all your type/class you would have noticed that you were using a type and not a variable).